# How does Fourier series apply to signals?

Tags: signal, fourier

I have the complex form of Fourier serie:

[image]

It says that a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> are real numbers, while c is a complex number. I need Fourier serie to represent an electrical signal that should transmit bits. In this case, what do a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> represent? How do I calculate them?

Comment: Where are ai and bi?

Comment: For ai I mean a generic a, so a0, a1 and so on. I should have called it an.

Comment: you should check your 1st equation - the index n is not present within the Sin or Cos, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @rawbrawb Are you quite sure? The first equation is quite common in books. For Bernard Sklar's Digital communications say \$x(\lambda)= \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_ncos(n \lambda)+b_nsin(n \lambda)) \$ It looks good to me.

Comment: @AndrejaKo look at your equation closely .. your answer is as I implied, his answer does not have the index, by index I mean n.

Comment: @rawbrawb It looks like I misread both your comment and the equation posted. The n elements are definitely missing there.

Comment: C is just the DC average.  I don't see anything complex (meaning relating to sqrt(-1)) here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fourier series can only be used to represent repetitive signals. So if you want to use Fourier series to represent a "signal that should transmit bits", it will have to be a signal that transmits the same bits over and over.

> what do *a<sub>n</sub>* and *b<sub>n</sub>* represent?

They represent the relative magnitude of the in-phase and quadrature components of the harmonics in your signal.

Which doesn't really tell you anything new.

What you've really done by taking the Fourier series is found a new way to represent all the information in your signal. Mathematically, you've transformed it to a new basis set.
This is useful because, for example, if you were to pass the signal through a filter with a known frequency response, it would be much easier to calculate the output by using the new frequency domain basis set, than directly using the time-domain representation.

> How do I calculate them?

Your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th equations are exactly how you calculate them.

Two key points. First, *c* is not a complex number, it is a real, as shown by the 4th equation.

Second, your first equation should be more like

\$g(t) = \dfrac{1}{2}c + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n{}\sin(2\pi{}nf_0t) + ...\$

Note the added *n* in the argument of the sine, as mentioned in the comments.

Also, notice I use *f<sub>0</sub>* instead of just *f*. Here *f<sub>0</sub>* is the **frequency at which your signal repeats**. That is, *f<sub>0</sub>* is \$\dfrac{1}{NT_b}\$, where *N* is the number of bits in your repeating sequence, and *T<sub>b</sub>* is the period of a single bit.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to apply Fourier transformation on the signal to time domain version of the signal to get the series of harmonics.

To do that, you integrate using following integral:

$$F(f)= \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(t)e^{-j2 \pi ft} dt$$

Remember that you have a way to transform sines and cosines in the following way:

$$ e^{j \theta}= cos(\theta)+jsin(\theta) $$
$$cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{j \theta}+e^{-j \theta}}{2}$$
$$sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{j \theta}+e^{-j \theta}}{2j} $$

So you'll get functions of e to the power of something and transform them into sines and cosines. Each sine will be multiplied by some number and that number will be \$a_n\$ for that sine. Each cosine will be multiplied by a number and that number will be the \$b_n\$ for that cosine.

You can also get the specific \$n\$th harmonic using the formulas you provided. The \$g(t)\$ is your signal and to get say third cosine part, you'll use following formula: $$b_3=\frac{2}{T}\int_0^Tcos(2 \pi 3 f t)dt$$ Do note that you have to integrate over whole period, but you don't have to integrate from 0 to T. In some cases integration from say \$\frac{-T}{2}\$ to \$ \frac{T}{2}\$ or some other value may be easier as long as you integrate over whole T.

If this doesn't answer your question, please post comment and explain what isn't clear.